# Pytest: Database access denied while running unit test

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

When I run my unit test using Django-pytest I keep getting the following error.
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'ruach'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")`. I am using an sqlite database locally which requires no password and using the decorator `@pytest.mark.django_db` to read back inserted values in the database so I am unsure what else could be causing this.

I have run unit tests successfully in the past with the configuration so I am puzzled as to what is causing test runner to be denied access.

settings.py

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

tests.py

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_and_save_invoices():
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else (perhaps a `python manage.py runserver` command) is probably using your `db.sqlite3` file mentioned in your `settings.py`.

Make sure you don't have any running commands, and try deleting your `db.sqlite3` file just to be sure.

Once your tests are working again, isolate them from your dev environment by [creating a custom settings module](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html) that uses a different database file.